# When to update a form based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a number input element in my form, which generates or deletes other fields based on its value.

If I call the function to generate them as soon as the user changes number (`.on('input', function() {...})`), I have the following use case issue: let's say the user inputs '10', and 10 fields are generated; the user fills them up, and then notices he needs one more. If he just clicks on the arrow up to get to 11, a new field is created and everything works, but if he deletes the '0' from '10', before he's able to write '11', the other 9 fields disappear and all inserted data is lost.

If, instead, I call the function after the user is done (using `.focusout(function() {...})`), it's too slow as other fields won't appear until the user gets out of the field.

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) so nothing will change until the input box is left

Comment: It think http://ux.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: `"it's too slow as other fields won't appear until the user gets out of the field"` - The problem you *just described* was that the other method was too *fast* as other fields *did* appear/disappear before the user got out of the field.  Which do you want?  One approach might be to disable typing in the field so the user *must* use the incremental up/downs.  Another option might be to remove the field entirely and just create visual up/down clickable elements and handle it all in JavaScript.  There are pros and cons with any approach you take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really consider using the `focusout` event. Creating a typing timer based on user's last key pressed may sound even more slow and confusing for your user.

Although, there's a UX section of SO (https://ux.stackexchange.com/) where you could find excellent UX designer's suggestions!

Comment: Thanks and sorry, didn't know about the UX section, is it possible to move the topic there?
I was thinking about adding a timer, I wonder if it would be that bad and confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such integration between the two sites. Anyway, the timer is really confusing, 'cause the user can't hardly tell the updating interval. Noticing that leaving the field will trigger the update is more clear for everybody nowadays.

Comment: Well, I could also use both focusout and a delay to trigger the function... Will give it a try and check how it feels.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the user data in a internal object such as a array or a json, so even if the number of fields change the data wont be lost.

Comment: This is technically the best solution, but a bit overkill in my specific case.